# У меня есть текст кода в String переменной. Можно ли его выполнить?

Tags: java

Есть переменная `String code;` в ней записан код одного метода. Можно ли его выполнить с помощью каких-либо библиотек или как-то иначе? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: один метод - вроде нет, класс - в принципе можно, в [ответе на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28890356/5661663) есть ссылка на проект на гитхабе

Comment: спасибо сейчас испробую!

Comment: Ошибку выдает((

Comment: @zRrr Это обертка над javac. Если на клиентской машине нет компилятора, то эта библиотека не поможет.

Comment: С недавних пор использую Groovy для составления скриптов. Может выполняться из строки, только это будет метод совсем другого класса. Но экземпляр своего класса всегда можно передать в скрип.

Comment: Не подскажите где можно прочитать про groovy? (Я новичок и немного лень рыться в тонне информации)

Comment: @free_ze можно tools.jar вместе с приложением таскать, хотя он большой. Можно после мелкой доработки кода по ссылке использовать ecj. В общем, это решаемая проблема.

Comment: У меня все равно при использовании такого способа вылетает ошибка(

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть под рукой javac, то можно скомпилировать и рефлекшном вызвать. Иначе - никак.

Comment: Жаль( Но все равно спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

[ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html)

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
Object result = engine.eval("4*5");
```

Comment: Разве это не js? Мне нужно чтобы код мог обращаться к другим методам и классам программы

Comment: @dhred, это java, метод `eval()`

Comment: @Doofy Внутри эвала javascript, из которого нельзя обращаться к внешнему Java-коду напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Есть библиотека под названием [MVEL](https://github.com/mvel/mvel).

Если передать туда строку вида `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc.exe")`, то калькулятор запустится.

UPD.
Есть класс

```
package my.pkg

public class MyClass {
  private int i;

  public MyClass(int i) {
     this.i = i;
  } 

  public void out() {
    System.out.println("This my variable " + i);
  }

  public int getI() {
    return this.i;
  }
}
```

тогда можно в [executor](https://github.com/mvel/mvel/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mvel2/MVEL.java#L904) передать такой код

```
"new my.pkg.MyClass(5).out()";
```

И в консоль ( откуда была запущена java) выведется

```
This my variable 5
```

Если же в executor передать такой код

```
"new my.pkg.MyClass(5).getI()"
```

То результатом будет интовая переменная 5

Comment: Мне кажется вы не совсем поняли вопрос... Либо я дурак

Comment: пример строки с кодом можете добавить в вопрос?

Comment: Эту строку будет вводить пользователь в textArea

Comment: Это некое подобие сайтов - игр для обучения программированию